# Why does LDAP requires a two step "login" (connect and then bind)

Tags: ldap

There's this thing I don't understand concerning LDAP (conceptually speaking, and - at least so I think - not tied to a particular implementation).

I noticed that a typical LDAP client library(for example apache DS) does a connect() first (for which some servers might require username/password), and then executes a bind() operation (which also requires username and password).

Questions:

- What is the point of this two step operation in LDAP?
- Does it add extra security?
- Why not just a single step ?
- What is the conceptual signification of these two steps ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When an LDAP client connects to an LDAP server, that connection is *unauthenticated*. Clients use the BIND operation to authenticate the connection. The server then processes requests on the connection using the authorization state of the connection with the privileges and access control thereto.

Some (if not most) LDAP APIs offer a single-step connection and BIND, for which one must provide the credentials of the user, or a pre-constructed BIND request (there are different types of BIND requests, simple and SASL). In the case you describe, the API is most likely establishing a connection to the server and then issuing the BIND request to the server. If this is successful, then the connection's authorization state is set. This would be a "convenience" method for clients.

Separating the connection from the BIND (the two steps you mention), is done so that the same connection can be used with different authorization states. Each BIND resets the authorization state of the connection. The LDAP client can connect, then BIND using one user and credentials, perform some operations as that user, then send another BIND request on the same connection to change the authorization state to that of a different user. This enables the client and server to be more efficient since the connection need not be made more than once. This is supported by LDAPv3.

The UNBIND request's name is a relic of LDAPv2, which did not allow multiple authorization states per connection. UNBIND is not the opposite of BIND, and it does disconnect as you discovered. LDAP clients using LDAPv3 can transmit a BIND request to change the authorization state of the connection. The misnamed UNBIND request does not "un-authorize" a state, it merely disconnects the LDAP client from the LDAP server.

#### see also:

- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Authentication Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/authentication-best-practices.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm using apache DS and apparently, when doing unbind(), this also triggers a disconnect. Hence I thought these two were tied together, but I see now that it's a specific library thing rather than general issue.

Comment: The `UNBIND` request's name is a relic of LDAPv2, which did not allow multiple authorization states per connection. `UNBIND` is not the opposite of `BIND`, and it does disconnect as you discovered.

Comment: I did not knew this, so thanks a lot. Do you know if there are common ldap servers that exclusively support LDAPv2 ?

Comment: The servers with which I am familiar support both v2 and v3, and some professional-quality servers can be configured to reject one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a difference!

**Connect()** refers to the connection to a LDAP server on a specified hostname and port, as the **bind ()** binds to the LDAP directory with specified RDN and password.

Hope this is helpful!